# c# minimum of two numbers if one or both is greater than 0

Tags: c#

The logic I'm looking for is if either of the numbers are >= 0 (which they don't have to be), then return the minimum of the two that is also greater than 0. The code I've written for it is so ugly that I'm ashamed to post it!

EDIT: 
Samples 
1, -1 => 1
5,6 => 5
-1,-1 => 0

(if both are less than 0, return 0)

Comment: What do you want to return if the numbers are less than 0? Sample input and expected output for various cases would be helpful.

Comment: how ugly can it be, please post it anyway.

Comment: Learning from experience @Richard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this too ugly?

```
private int GetSmallestNonNegative(int a , int b)
{
    if (a >= 0 && b >= 0)
        return Math.Min(a,b);
    else if (a >= 0 && b < 0)
        return a;
    else if (a < 0 && b >= 0)
        return b;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How bout `Math.Max(Math.Min(a,b), 0)`?

Comment: I would probably right this code for a prod env too.. Clean and concise.. No head scratching.. +1 from me

Comment: You don't need the checks for `a >= 0` and `b >= 0` in the conditions. Basically this is the equivalent of my first solution, but the other way up and using `if / else` instead of conditionals.

Comment: @Jon: comes down to a question of whether you like the stacked conditional operator I guess.

Comment: @Jimmy: Agreed. I find it's a nice pattern once you're used to it.

Comment: @Alxandr so many upvotes for your wrong answer? your answer is incorrect. you get 0 if a or b is 0

Answer (score 18):

I'm going to try my psychic powers, and assuming that if both are zero, you want to return 0.

In other words:

```
return x < 0 && y < 0 ? 0
     : x < 0 ? y
     : y < 0 ? x
     : Math.Min(x, y);
```

I'm sure I can do better though...

If they're *not* both greater than 0, then at least one will be less than zero, so you just care about the greater of them, or 0 if they're both less than zero. Otherwise, we just take the minimum.

```
return x < 0 || y < 0 ? Math.Max(Math.Max(x, y), 0) : Math.Min(x, y);
```

If you don't care much about performance, you could use:

```
new[] { x, y }.Where(z => z > 0)
              .DefaultIfEmpty() // Make sure there's at least one entry
              .Min();
```

Frankly none of these are terribly nice, IMO. I'd want a comment with any of them...

Comment: You could save one `Max` call using `Math.Max(0, Math.Min(x,y))`

Comment: @nikie: except `x=5`, `y=-1` returns 0

Comment: @hatchet: No, it should return `1` if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: @hatchet, yep sorry if it wasn't clear. -1, 1 should return 1

Comment: Though I could nt believe the answer got 6 up votes when it was incorrect.. @Jon were u trying to be evil and try what you suggested the other day in 1 of ur tweets

Comment: @zzzz: Unfortunately not deliberate at all. I'm clearly trying to do too many things...

Comment: The reason behind being distracted... https://plus.google.com/109123888989768381249/posts/J9P2dadbuu9

Comment: 404. That’s an error.
The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: @zzzz: Gah - sorry, didn't make it public. Try this: https://plus.google.com/109123888989768381249/posts/WX2YybY3q72

Comment: LOL. When Skeet posts, people upvote. Why bother thinking first?

Comment: I'm scared to tell him that his second one still doesn't work.

Comment: @Marc: Darn it! Editing again... Could you check now? I'm clearly not capable of checking correctly myself :(

Comment: @Jon, doesn't your last solution require a declaration as an anonymously typed array? i.e. `new[] {x,y}` ?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is simple, extendable to any number arguments, and reflects the original wording of the question ("minimum of a set of numbers that is also greater than or equal to 0") reasonably well:

```
new[] { a,b,0 }.Where(x => x >= 0).Min();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If (a>=0 &&b>=0)
 return Math.Min(a,b);

var min =Math.Max(a,b);
 return min<0 ? 0: min;
```

Comment: Na it's fine.. If it's or then the negative no will be returned

Answer (score 1):

try (although no beauty):

```
Math.Max (Math.Sign (Math.Max (x,0)), Math.Sign (Math.Max (y, 0))) == 0 ? 0 : ((Math.Sign (Math.Max (x,0)) + Math.Sign (Math.Max (y, 0))) == 2 ? Math.Min (x, y): Math.Max (x, y ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (a >=0 && b>=0) ? Math.Min(a,b) : (Math.Max(a,b) < 0 ? 0 : Math.Max(a,b));
```

Comment: Fails when both are negative... Look at my answer

Comment: Min isn't sufficient, because only numbers >= 0 can be considered.

Comment: That's an exact duplicate if my answer.. :/

Comment: @zzzz: Huh? How is it "exact" duplicate? Just because the logic is same?

Answer (score 1):

```
return (a >= 0 || b >= 0) ? Math.Min(Math.Max(0,a), Math.Max(0,b)) : 0;
```

(edit) small change for slightly better performance when either are zero

```
return (a > 0 || b > 0) ? Math.Min(Math.Max(0,a), Math.Max(0,b)) : 0;
```

Comment: (but Jon's is still better with only one Max)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be helpful.

```
Max= ((num1+num2)+Math.Abs(num1-num2))/2
and Min= ((num1+num2)-Math.Abs(num1-num2))/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have new C# features, you could use `switch` expressions and `ValueTuple` pattern matching to only test each variable once:

```
var ans = (x < 0, y < 0) switch {
            (true, true) => 0,
            (false, true) => x,
            (true, false) => y,
            (false, false) => Math.Min(x, y)
        };
```

You could also flip the tests around, depending on which is more important or you think is more readable:

```
var ans = (x >= 0, y >= 0) switch {
            (false, false) => 0,
            (true, false) => x,
            (false, true) => y,
            (true, true) => Math.Min(x, y)
        };
```